# How to access processResources expand build.gradle data using info actuator endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

My build.gradle:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('application-bootrun.properties') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}

allprojects {
    ...
    version = '0.3.0'
    ...
}
```

My application-bootrun.properties:
...

```
info.build.version=${version}
```

When I access /info actuator endpoint, I get:

```
"build": {
        "version": "${version}"
    },
```

How to get "0.3.0" as "version" ?

Comment: After you invoke `bootRun`, look in the `build/resources/main` directory for `application-bootrun.properties` and open it up. Do you see `${version}` or `0.3.0` in it?